# Creating Loop to populate XML file in notepad in Excel VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, loops

I am trying to get a loop to work to generate an XML file in Notepad. Creating the XML file as well as the header and footer is fine. The issue I’m having is getting the script to be flexible. The script will be run periodically with the number of input data lines varying. The script I currently have does generate a working XML file for the correct number of users but the populated data is repeated from the first input line. I’ve racked my brains over this and searched on here and other sites but I haven’t found anything that I have been able to apply. I normally only use VBA to generate .xlsx files so working in notepad is a bit out of my comfort zone. I tried using “Dim i As Integer” but got nowhere with Range("D10" & i).Value etc. Any help would be appreciated. Please see the script below:

**Code**

```
Sub Macro1()

    ' Macro1 Macro

    unique = Range("C1").Value
    creation = Range("C2").Value
    Users = Range("C10:C1010").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    Total = Range("c4").Value
    batch = Range("C3").Value
    valuedate = Range("C6").Value
    myfilename = batch
    masterfile = "C:\temp\TEXTFILE.XML"
    'LastRow = Range("C10", Range("C10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Dim src As String, dst As String, fl As String
    Dim rfl As String

    FileNum = FreeFile ' next free filenumber
    'Open "C:\Temp\TEXTFILE.TXT" For Output As #FileNum ' creates the new file

    Open "C:\temp\TEXTFILE.XML" For Output As #1

    'Header Script (no issue)
    ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
    NumRows = Range("C10", Range("C10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    '      ' Select cell C10.
    Range("C10").Select

    '      ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
    For x = 1 To NumRows
        '         ' Insert your code here.
        ' generate line specific data

        Print #FileNum, "         " & "<CdtTrfTxInf>" & vbNewLine &
        "            " & "<XXXXX>" & vbNewLine &
        "               " & "<XXXXXXX>"; Format(Month(valuedate), "00") &  Format(Day(valuedate), "00") & "-01<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "               " & "<XXXXXXXX" & """XXXXX""" & ">" & Range("D10").Value & 
        "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "               " & "<XXXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "                  " & "<XXXXXX>" & Range("H10").Value & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "               " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "               " & "<XXXXXX>" & Range("C10").Value & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "               " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "                  " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & Range("G10").Value & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "               " & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXXXXX>/XXXXXXXXXX/R/<XXXXXXXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "               " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & Range("E10").Value & "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "            " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
        "         " & "<XXXXXXXXXXXXX>"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How about using a placeholder somewhere on your spreadsheet to check against that will flag whether or not that row has already been exported, if it has then do not export, and if it hasn't export that line and add the flag to that record.

Comment: Close: Range("D" & 10 + i).Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some hints:**

- Always use `Option Explicit` and declare your variables. You can use `Type` in order to structure related informations needed.
- Try to use fully qualified references to a range, sheet or workbook.
- Avoid looping through ranges for single values - arrays are much faster.

I used a helper function to get the column number, so that your code will be easier to read, if you want to get the array value e.g. from column "H" (=8):

> v(x, s2Col("H"))

Of course you can also use `v(x, 8)`

**Declaration head of your module**

```
Option Explicit
Type TValues
     unique As Variant
     creation As Variant
     Users As Long
     Total As Variant
     batch As Variant
     valuedate As Variant
End Type
Dim MyValues As TValues
```

**Main procedure**

```
Sub Macro1()
' Purpose: create xml from sheet information using a 1-based 2-dim datafield array
Dim src As String, dst As String, fl As String
Dim rfl As String
Dim v                   ' variant (to receive one based 2dim data field array)
Dim oWs  As Worksheet   ' worksheet
Dim myfilename As String
Dim masterfile As String
Dim s          As String
Dim FileNum    As Long
Dim numRows    As Long
Dim x          As Long
Set oWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")
With MyValues
  .unique = oWs.Range("C1").value
  .creation = oWs.Range("C2").value
  .Users = oWs.Range("C10:C1010").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
  .Total = oWs.Range("c4").value
  .batch = oWs.Range("C3").value
  .valuedate = oWs.Range("C6").value

  myfilename = .batch
  masterfile = "C:\temp\TEXTFILE.XML"
'LastRow = Range("C10", Range("C10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

FileNum = FreeFile ' next free filenumber
'Open "C:\Temp\TEXTFILE.TXT" For Output As #FileNum ' creates the new file
 Open "D:\temp\TEXTFILE.XML" For Output As #1

'Header Script (no issue)
' ...
' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  numRows = Range("C10", oWs.Range("C10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
' create a one based 2-dim datafield array
  v = oWs.Range("A10:H" & numRows + 9).value      ' plus 9 rows for information header

' loop throug array
For x = 1 To numRows
    '

    s = "         " & "<CdtTrfTxInf>" & vbNewLine & "            " & "<XXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "               " & "<XXXXXXX>" & Format(Month(.valuedate), "00") & Format(Day(.valuedate), "00") & "-01<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & "            " & "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "               " & "<XXXXXXXX" & """XXXXX""" & ">" & v(x, s2Col("D")) & "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "               " & "<XXXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "                  " & "<XXXXXX>" & v(x, s2Col("H")) & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "               " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "               " & "<XXXXXX>" & v(x, s2Col("C")) & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "               " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "                  " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & v(x, s2Col("G")) & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "               " & "<XXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXXXXX>/XXXXXXXXXX/R/<XXXXXXXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "               " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & v(x, s2Col("E")) & "<XXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "            " & "<XXXXXXXX>" & vbNewLine & _
    "         " & "<XXXXXXXXXXXXX>"
    Print #FileNum, s
Next
End With    ' Type MyValues
' don't forget to add a closing tag to receive a well formed XML file, e.g. ...
' Print #FileNum, "</root>"
'
' close text file
Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

**Helper function (cf. above hints)**

Gets the column number from a given column letter:

```
Public Function s2Col(ByVal sCol As String) As Long
' Purpose: return column number, e.g. "H" -> 8
  s2Col = Range(sCol & ":" & sCol).Column
End Function
```

**Note**

Of course, there exist other ways to create xml files (e.g. referencing a MSXML2.DomDocument60 object via XMLDOM methods).

Comment: This worked a treat with a few amendments. Thanks for your help!